# Save in global variable list of firebase documents to display in the console, in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm making a to-do list app

I need to keep an up-to-date to-do list in the global const array.

I found this array in the constructor, output it to HTML `{{ todo.name }}`, everything works fine, but

I can't output this to the console, and don't understand what is in the array instead, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../shared/services/auth.service";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { formatDate } from "@angular/common";

export interface Todo {
    name: string;
    isDone: boolean;
    priority: string;
    creationDate: any;
    creationTime: any;
    id: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-todo-list',
    templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./todo-list.component.sass']
})

@Injectable()

export class TodoListComponent {
    userData: any; // Save logged in user data
    inputValue: string = '';

    listTodos: AngularFirestoreCollection<Todo>;
    itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Todo>;

    items: Observable<Todo[]>; // All Todo
    todosHigh: Observable<Todo[]>; // Category

    public now: Date = new Date();

    constructor(
        public afs: AngularFirestore,
        public authService: AuthService,
        public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    ) {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if (user) {
                this.userData = user;
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

                const dataDay = formatDate(this.now, 'ddMMyyyy', 'en-US');
                const userId = this.userData.uid;

                this.listTodos = afs.collection<Todo>('users').doc(userId)
                        .collection<Todo>('todo-list');

                // All todo
                this.items = this.listTodos.doc('todoDay_' + dataDay)
                        .collection<Todo>('todo-daily').valueChanges();

                // High category todo
                this.todosHigh = this.listTodos.doc('todoDay_' + dataDay)
                        .collection<Todo>('todo-daily', ref => ref
                            .where('priority', '==', 'high')).valueChanges();

                console.log(this.todosHigh); // This dont work

            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('user', null);
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            }
        })
    }

    // Example f for show todo array
    showList() {
        const dataDay = formatDate(this.now, 'ddMMyyyy', 'en-US');
        const userId = this.userData.uid;
        // All todo
        this.items = this.afs.collection<Todo>('users')
                .doc(userId)
                .collection<Todo>('todo-list')
                .doc('todoDay_' + dataDay)
                .collection<Todo>('todo-daily')
                .valueChanges();
        console.log(this.items); // This dont work
    }

}
```

Now the console looks like this:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object
```

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the docs from angularfire2, not sure if you use it, **valueChanges()** returns an Observable. That is what your console output says. It prints information about the Observable. [angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges)

To resolve the Observable you need to subscribe to it.